# What does また mean in 右、左、または、まっすぐ?

Tags: meaning, words

What does また mean here:

> 車は右、左、**また**は、まっすぐに行ってもいいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this sentece または is to be seen as a **whole** and means "or".